# Byobu's F2 key has no effect anymore, but Ctrl+F2 is fine

Tags: byobu

I used to be able to create new sessions with F2, and split panes with Shift/Ctrl + F2.

But since yesterday, F2 has no effect anymore. The other F2s and F shortcuts from byobu still work just fine. When I press F2, I am getting a bell from my terminal emulator.

I have not edited any of the `~/.byobu` config files.

Using byobu 5.125 and tmux 2.6 in Terminator with bash.